# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'QWebEngineView'

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside2, qwebengineview

I have been using the QT designer tool which saves GUIs as a XML template. PySide2 is able to covert this to a Python Class file.

Utilizing the tool for an XML that includes QWebEngineView

```
pyside2-uic GUI_NEW.ui > ui_main.py
```

The first few lines of the ui_main.py call for

```
################################################################################
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.15.2
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

from QWebEngineView import QWebEngineView
```

running the file that utilizes this, results in:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'QWebEngineView'
```

So far I have tried

- Trying PySide6 over PySide 2
- Replaced the import line with

  *from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView*

  The Application runs but completely hangs
- pip install PyQtWebEngine

[image]

- pip install PyQt5==5.11.3
- Cleaning up, installing all references to Qt (Pyside, PyQT, etc), and re-installing
- Attempted all the above on python 3.6 - 3.8

Comment: share the GUI_NEW.ui content

Comment: The first import line you tried is wrong, since `QWebEngineView` is a class, not a module. The second attempt should be correct, if it hangs you should try to run it from a terminal or prompt and post the output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option, you don't have it.

Then try this option:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
```

That is, an example of a string:

```
self.webView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self.centralwidget)
```

**But**, unfortunately `Qt`, `PyQt` and `PySide` should never be used together. Most problems occur when trying to re-display a widget created with a binding with another one created with a different binding.

The solution is simple: you either use PyQt5 and use `QtWebEngineWidgets`, or `PySide2`.

As a last resort, try installing a newer version (5.12)(`PyQt5`) and install `PyQtWebEngine` separately.

Comment: well the end goal here is rendering HTML content. Doing the above doesnt call QWebEngineView so I did this isntead. from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView which resulted in TypeError: QWebEngineView(parent: QWidget = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QFrame'

Comment: I will stick to PySide2, Using "from PySide2 import QtWebEngineWidgets" freezes the app immediately. If I can figure why that would be helpful. Nothing comes up in the console. Its also weird how pyside-uic will import everything from pyside2 except for the webview module

Comment: @idroid8 I added an alternative `QtWebEngineWidgets`

Comment: QtWebkit is deprecated and support has been removed since Qt 5.5.

Comment: @musicamante You are right, I suggested another option

Comment: @idroid8 I suggested another option.

Comment: "Qt, PyQt and PySide should never be used together." that's imprecise. First of all, PyQt and PySide ***are*** Qt. Then, the problem is that PyQt and PySide are two different python *bindings* for Qt (which is C++), and they only "behave" very similarly, so not only they shouldn't be used together, they simply *cannot*, and problems don't rise up just when "re-display" widgets, but even when creating Qt object instances of different bindings. That said, QtWebEngine modules are available for both, the only difference might be in the install procedure which might vary depending on the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I stuck to PySide2 (option 2), creating a new project specific python environment that did not involve PyQt5. This prevented the application from hanging with zero console errors.